# Attempting to print array elements recursively

Tags: c, arrays, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>


int printArray(a[], unsigned int n){
    if (n == 4){
        printf("%d", a[4]);
    }
    else {
        printf("%d", printArray(a,n+1)); // here is the error, I know. But why?
    }
}


int main(){

    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    printArray(a,0);

}
```

I am a begginer with C. I am trying to print each of the elements of the array, but it only prints the last one correctly, and not the former ones. I know there's something about recursive way wrong. It's the first time I use recursive way without return and using printf. Maybe is this that misleaded me?

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
5
0
1
1
0
```

Comment: You do not returning anything so what the second printf suppose to print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should print the array item, not the return value of the function, Use this code

```
int printArray(int *a, unsigned int n){
    if (n == 4){
        printf("%d", a[4]);
    }
    else {
        printf("%d", a[n]);
        printArray(a,n+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't done pointers yet, but if I just replace *a with what I wrote initially, a[] . It works anyway!